# How to detect the end of execution of a shell script in VBA Excel?

Tags: python, vba, shell, execution

With this code, my program runs endlessly because the status of my oExec object does not change.

```
sub test()
    Dim oShell As Object, oExec As Object
    Dim exePath As String, scriptPath As String, oCmd As String

    Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    exePath = """C:\Applications\Python\Python38-32\python.exe"""
    scriptPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Scripts\"

    oCmd = "python.exe " & scriptPath & scriptName
    Set oExec = oShell.Exec(oCmd)
    'Waiting for the shell script to finish executing 
    While oExec.Status = 0
    Wend
end sub
```

Could you, please, help me ?

Regards

Comment: I think you can try [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/windows-api/determine-when-a-shelled-process-ends).

Comment: @Abdallah El-Yaddak. It's impeccable, I will keep this method in my favorites. Many thanks.